# CreateDirectory() or filesystem::create_directory() fails on a Windows 10 Virtual Machine with administrator rights

Tags: c++, directory, virtual-machine, virtualbox, administrator

When I use `std::filesystem::create_directory()` of the C++ filesystem or `CreateDirectory()` on a shared folder of a virtual machine it fails to create a directory when I am running the application as administrator. However, when I run it normally on an account and not as administrator, it seems to work fine.

I am using VirtualBox with windows 10 as host system and also windows 10 within the virtual machine. The shared folder is auto mounted and visible within the virtual machine as the E:\ drive. The error that is returned says "Path not found" and the error code given by `CreateDirectory()` is number 3 on this list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-. I've used multiple ways to return this error, for `std::filesystem::create_directory()` I've used its second argument and with `CreateDirectory()` I've used `GetLastError()`.

Is there any option to run these functions with no administrator privilege when the application itself runs with administrator rights?

Or is there any other solution?

Example code using filesystem that produces the error:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::filesystem::path targetPath = "E:\\TestPath";
    std::filesystem::create_directory(targetPath);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using relative paths? Show us the call to std::filesystem::create_directory.

Comment: where are you creating the directory? what are the permissions on the parent directory? We need a [mcve].

Comment: What you ask (running part of code impersonating a different user) is very OS dependent. But there may be alternative approaches to solve your problem, please describe better what you want to obtain and in which scenario.

Comment: There is probably a difference of environment.   For example, using a relative path, which resolves differently for different accounts.   Without a [mcve] accompanied by such information (environment variables, current working directory, etc) no better guesses are possible.

Comment: what is error code returned by `CreateDirectory` ? always begin from this. call `GetLastError()` or better `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` after this api fail

Comment: Are you running _with administrator rights_ or _as administrator_? They're very much not the same thing.

Comment: I am logged in as normal user and run the program as administrator.